# ffmpeg, info dump on stderr

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I'm running ffmpeg from a standalone java class, and reading the stderr. However, my log file is getting flooded with messages like

"frame=  581 fps= 52 q=28.0 size=    2074kB time=17.98 bitrate= 944.9kbits/s"

Is there any way to turn these messages off and only capture the errors if any? If that's not an option, is there atleast some way to pipe these messages to stdout, instead of stderr?

Thanks,
tekgro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh yea super easy just put a -v 0 in your ffmpeg command (for some reason i personally had no success messing with the loglevel)

Answer (score 2):

If you're running it on the command line, FFMpeg has an option for logging level:

`-loglevel loglevel`

Where `loglevel` is one of `quiet`, `panic`, `fatal`, `error`, `warning`, `info`, `verbose`, or `debug`.